# spring data mongo and spring data elasticsearch usage in pom.xm

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-elasticsearch

I want to use both the dependencies in pom.xml as below;

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
<version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
<version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Elastisearch is working fine, but mongo is not working.

Which versions are compatible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just followed the below link for version compatibility;
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework.data%7Cspring-data-releasetrain%7CDijkstra-RELEASE%7Cpom 
It is working fine